# SQL Subquery, Invalid Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

TSQL Says : Invalid Column Name 'VehicleId'

```
SELECT 
(SELECT dbo.Vehicles.Id FROM dbo.Vehicles JOIN dbo.Movements 
ON dbo.Vehicles.Id=dbo.Movements.VehicleId 
WHERE dbo.Movements.Id=dbo.Alarms.MovementId) As VehicleId
FROM [dbo].[Alarms] 
WHERE 
VehicleId =1
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Please show us the schema

Comment: Show us a schema of your tables so that we can understand it a little better

Comment: Try xtable.VehicleId = 1

Comment: I think youcanot use the alias from `select` in `where` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT Alarms.*
FROM dbo.Vehicles JOIN 
        dbo.Movements ON dbo.Vehicles.Id=dbo.Movements.VehicleId JOIN
        dbo.Alarms ON dbo.Movements.Id=dbo.Alarms.MovementId
WHERE VehicleId =1
```

Answer (score 1):

The table `Alarms` does not have a column named `VehicleId`

The where clause does not use the alias

```
SELECT 
(SELECT dbo.Vehicles.Id FROM dbo.Vehicles JOIN dbo.Movements 
ON dbo.Vehicles.Id=dbo.Movements.VehicleId 
WHERE dbo.Movements.Id=dbo.Alarms.MovementId) As VehicleId
FROM [dbo].[Alarms] 
WHERE 
VehicleId = 1 -- this is wrong
```

Rather than using a correlated subquery try multiple joins

```
SELECT dbo.Vehicles.Id 
FROM dbo.Vehicles 
JOIN dbo.Movements 
ON dbo.Vehicles.Id = dbo.Movements.VehicleId 
JOIN dbo.Alarms
ON dbo.Alarms.MovementId = dbo.Movement.Id
WHERE dbo.Movements.VehicleId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Alarms.*
from 
(SELECT dbo.Vehicles.Id FROM dbo.Vehicles JOIN dbo.Movements 
ON dbo.Vehicles.Id=dbo.Movements.VehicleId 
WHERE dbo.Movements.Id=dbo.Alarms.MovementId) As VehicleId
join  [dbo].[Alarms] 
on VehicleId.ID = Alarms.vehicleID
WHERE 
VehicleId =1
```